# Regarding implementing a new transport protocol

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, raw-sockets

I am trying to implement my own Transport Layer Protocol like TCP which will be used by some application, on top of network layer using raw sockets API in Linux. I am working on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have been able to send and receive packets.

Now in the part of implementing the Transport Protocol, I am looking forward to write some functions like

connect(int sockfd) - To establish connection to the server.

send_data(int sockfd, char* data) - To send data

receive_data(int sockfd, char* data) - To receive data

close(int sockfd) - close the connection

Also since I am trying to implement protocol like TCP, to keep the protocol reliable I want to send acknowledgement for each received data packet. I have made my own TCP like header as follows

```
typedef struct rtlp_hdr
{
    int         checksum; 
    short int   src_port;  //defined by us
    short int   des_port;  //defined by us
    int         seq_no;
    int         ack_no;

}rtlp_hdr;
```

Now in the implementation of the send_data function after I send a data packet I wait to receive the acknowledgement for the next data packet for given time, and if I don't receive any ack or I receive a corrupted ack( after checking the checksum) I resend the data. I am facing problems in creating the corresponding receive_data function for the same, like how would I know that the ack sent for the received data has been successfully delivered to the sender, since there is no ack for ack.

If anyone has any ideas what can I do or if I am going in the wrong direction please correct me. thanks in advance.

I have already written code for the connect(int sockfd) using 3-way handshaking that is working fine, I can share that.

Comment: if the sender sends the same data again then apparently he didn't receive the ack.

Comment: Yeah that is good on the paper, but how to implement that thing?

Comment: the receiver should rely on the sequence number and if he receives an out of sequence packet just throw it away. The sender is responsible to send the right data

Comment: It is also good to take a look at this http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/jun/7/understanding-tcp-sequence-acknowledgment-numbers/

Comment: stack overflow is no discussion forum. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: if it's not purely for education purposes, I'd think twice about implementing it over raw sockets, because of NATs/Firewalls

Comment: @Pooya *the receiver should rely on the sequence number and if he receives an out of sequence packet just throw it away.*  Do not do that.  That would mean losing packet N means the receiver throws away all packets after N until a retransmitted N is received - then every packet that was thrown away will also have to be retransmitted.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: that is correct but as he said he wanted to implementing a new protocol which he didn't mention about having a window system. So first of all I suggest he can overcome this with just send and receive one packet at a time

Comment: @Pooya That would be a terribly slow protocol.  But probably a good learning experience.

Comment: @AndrewHenle indeed it is. Actually it is reinventing the wheel, it takes some time to make it work

Comment: The attributes of `int` `short` depend of the platform.  Since this is to communicate _between_ platforms , recommend fixed width types like `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`, and specified endian, for the message fields.

Comment: This is off topic. It is really about protocol design, which belongs on [the CS site](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, there is no way to guarantee that a message arrives at the destination. If i understand your question right i hope the simple example below can help you.

You have a client A, and a server B. Client A sends a packet named A1 to B.
B saves the name of the last received packet, and replies to A with an ack.

If the ack makes it to the client it sends the next packet, named A2.

If, however, the ack is lost, the client resends the data named A1 after a while.
When the server receives A1 a second time (using the saved name), it can assume that the ack was lost.
The server then resends the ack, hoping that it will make it to the client this time. This continues as many times as neccessary.

As you see, the server does not need to know if the ack has been delivered to the client. The receiving of a duplicate packet tells the server that the ack was lost. (ignoring spurious timeouts for simplicity)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the *Byzantine Generals' problem* of protocols: there is never a guarantee that a message arrives. If you send a message to ack that the message arrived, it may not arrive; if you send a poll to enquire if the message has arrived, it may never arrive or its answer may never arrive...

So protocols can at best be "mostly reliable" and in your design you must include non-arrival, and your software must be able to cope with it. "The software" may mean all the way up to the application layer.